# aiohttp - Error: 400, message='invalid character in header'

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, httpx

I've started working with AioHttp to use async code in requests.
However, I've found that I encounter many pages that don't return a response.
Instead I get:
`Error: 400, message='invalid character in header'`

I've looked online for a way past this (maybe using a different decoding mechanism?), and came across this (and some similar) discussions on Github: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/5269

Basically it looks as though there is no real way past this, except for maybe using AIOHTTP_NO_EXTENSIONS=1, as shown here: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/5355, but I'm not sure exactly what is else is in these "extensions" that I might need.

Here is some example code that illustrates the issue:
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/5269#issuecomment-803565516

Currently the only way I see past this is moving to HTTPX, which is fine, but is still not even v1.0.0 (feels odd to use in a production environment).

I'm looking for any way past this issue, or possibly a good alternative for aiohttp.
Thanks!

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: I can, but do you need another example? The code in the github comment (last link) is more or less exactly what I run.

Comment: actually when i run git hub code is working for me

Comment: Are you sure? I get the exact error the author of the comment wrote down (invalid character..). I'm using python 3.8.9 and the latest version of aiohttp. What about you?

Comment: i am using python 3.7.0

Comment: Not sure how 3.7.0 would react, and what version of aiohttp you are using. The point is I'm not able to make it work on the latest aiohttp (3.7.4.post0)

Comment: I am using aiohttp(3.6.2) & believe me aiohttp some times behave strangely i know that , link of my code working https://imgur.com/a/3sKXsDc